# Comparing two lists from user input (lottery game)

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm trying to compare two lists to see if any numbers are alike. If there's a match, the user gets a point. I've tried several different approaches but I can't get it right. Any suggestions?

```py
num_list = [] # 5 numbers from the user, separated by ','
win_numbers = [] # 10 random numbers from randint

def get_numbers():
    '''
    Asks the user for five numbers

    '''

    player_numbers = input("Ange fem siffror [1-25] (avgränsa med ',') : ") 
    num_list.append(player_numbers) 
    player_numbers = player_numbers.split(",")
    numbers_as_int = [int(i) for i in player_numbers]

def random_numbers():
    '''
    This function generates the winning numbers
    and saves them to the list win_numbers
    '''

    for i in range(10):
        poll = random.randint(1,25) #Generates a random number
        if poll not in win_numbers: # Checks if number is already in the list
            win_numbers.append(poll) # Add the new number

def result():

    print(num_list)
    print(win_numbers)

    points = 0

    for w,n in zip(win_numbers,num_list):
        if w == n:
            points += 1


    print(points)
```

Comment: Are you using any particular language?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'll eat my hat if this isn't Python, so I've edited his tags to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

How exactly would you like the comparison to work? Based on what you said, perhaps this is what you're after:

```py
numbers_as_int = []

# ...

def result():
    points = 0

    for winner in win_numbers:
        if winner in numbers_as_int :
            points += 1

    # Do something with `points`
```